# jQuery Tabs and document.ready fn

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I used jQuery tabs to implement different versions of the same page in 3 tabs... I found out that if I load the first page then second and third tabs dont implement $.ready and whts inside it.

If I load the third tab then all tabs have proper jquery job done. The case is when I proceed forward I have the problem.

Is there any way to work around this?!

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're talking about.  Can you reproduce the problem with minimal code and show us that code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, but you could try to attach your $.ready code to a custom event on, say.. your pages `<body>` tag. That way, from within the parent page (the one with the tabs) you can trigger that custom event, something like:

```
 $("#custom_body_id").trigger("event_name");
```

You can trigger that event on the `load` event triggered by the tabs plugin. I'd recommend checking out the [plugin's doc](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-load)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey Guys! Thanks for ur concern..I know its Kinda Late reply but i found out wht the pblm was..There are no issues regarding fwd/bcwd processing..Actually it was because i used a input hidden element with a common class and instead of choosing the value of the element in current class based on the visibility of its parent i blindly chose val of tht element which always returns first assigned value..Issue is solved now.Thanks for ur concern.